# Is there a more elegant way (or a pattern) to implement groups of related classes

Tags: oop, class, design-patterns, generics

I'm trying to implement various groups of related classes, somewhat like this:

- MySQLDatabase
- MySQLTable (references an MySQLDatabase)
- MySQLRecord (references an MySQLTable)
- PostGreDatabase
- PostGreTable (references an PostGreDatabase)
- PostGreRecord (references an PostGreTable)
- OracleDatabase
- ...

Since the relative classes (MySQLTable, PostGreTable, etc..) have a lot of shared code I have implemented this with abstract parent classes and generics, like this:

```
class Database {}

class Table<DatabaseType> where DatabaseType : Database 
{
  public DatabaseType FDatabase; //this is what I mean by "references"
}

class Record<TableType, DatabaseType> where 
  DatabaseType : Database
  TableType : Table<DatabaseType> 
{
  public TableType FTable;
}

class MySQLDatabase : Database {}

class MySQLTable : Table<MySQLDatabase> 
{
  public string FCharset;
}

MySQLRecord : Record<MySQLTable, MySQLDatabase> {}

...
```

And I need this architecture to be able to:

- Prevent wrong references.

Ex: A MySQLTable can't reference a PostGreDatabase or a OracleDatabase, only a MySQLDatabase.

- Enable the programmer to access a object specific properties without the need for casting.

Example:

```
SomeMySQLRecord.FTable.FCharset = 'UTF-8';
```

instead of

```
((MySQLTable)SomeMySQLRecord.FTable).Charset = 'UTF-8';
```

I'm looking for a more elegant way (or a pattern) to do this, because the real groups of classes have more than 3 classes and the generics are really creeping the code. Example:

```
MyType : Type1<GType1, GType2, GType3, GType4> where
  GType1 : Type2,
  GType2 : Type3<GType1>,
  GType3 : Type4<GType1, GType2>,
  GType4 : Type5<GType2, GType1, Type2, GType3>
```

Answer (score 0):

Generics to me doesn't make sense here. Taking your own code:

```
Table<DatabaseType : Database>
MySQLTable : Table<MySQLDatabase>
```

One would assume MySQLTable to be also defined using generics because you are defining it as a child of Table:

```
MySQLTable<Something> : Table<MySQLDatabase>
```

How would you define *Something* here? It doesn't make sense.

If you are using Generics to achieve this:

*Ex: A MySQLTable can't reference a PostGreDatabase or a OracleDatabase, only a MySQLDatabase.*

I don't think that is the necessary and sufficient condition to use Generics.

Comment: Yes I'm using generics to achieve just that, because the other two alternatives, that I can think of, would be: copy-pasting a lot of my code and just changing the types or declaring properties using the abstract types, e.g. Having a Table property On a MySQLRecord instead of a MySQLTable property, and doing a lot of boilerplate type validation to ensure that this property can only accept a MySQLTable. Both of which violates the DRY principle.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a slightly different route, although I am not entirely sure if that would work in your particular case:

```
     public class Provider { }

    public class Oracle : Provider { }

    public class AbstractDatabase<T> where T : Provider
    {
        // Your base code here
    }

    public class AbstractTable<T> where T : Provider
    {
        public AbstractDatabase<T> FDatabase { get; set; }
        // Your base code here
    }

    public class AbstractRecord<T> where T : Provider
    {
        public AbstractTable<T> FTable { get; set; }
    }

    public class OracleDatabase : AbstractDatabase<Oracle> { }

    public class OracleTable : AbstractTable<Oracle>
    {
        public new OracleDatabase FDatabase { get; set; }

        // Your strongly typed code
        public OracleTable(OracleDatabase parent) { }
    }
```

Comment: But the generics creeping still persists

Comment: I see, could you give more specific example? I just want to see if doing it this way would reduce it.

Comment: Ok, I think in this solution you'll not see this chaining problem as you'd end up with code like: OracleRecord : AbstractRecord<Oracle> etc... whereas in your case you have to provide two parameters and then three, etc... with this solution it is enough to always provide only one parameter - provider type

Comment: Could you add my FDatabase and FTable fields to your code so I can better understand your solution?

Comment: wont do. I'm trying to avoid the need to cast OracleTable.FDatabase to OracleDatabase.

Comment: You will not have to. OracleTable.FDatabase will be of OracleDatabase type. If you use OracleDatabase class or internal generic properties are "collapsed" to non-generic counterparts.

Comment: Ok, I think I missed your point... you can work around it as in updated code

Comment: could work, but I would need to override a substantial portion of the children classes code, partially defeating the use of common parent classes to avoid boilerplate code. On the plus side I wouldn't need generics thus allowing compatibility with older versions of Delphi.